# asyncore server: Request resulting in "socket.error'>:[Errno 32] Broken pipe)"

Tags: python, asyncore

I'm writing an asyncore server which fetches info from another module in same process and writes it back to client. The info basically is a dictionary where for each key we have a queue of messages. I'm required to dump the length of each queue. The code runs fine on a test machine but as soon as I install it on a production server I start getting following error message : "socket.error'>:[Errno 32] Broken pipe)".

This is the server:

```
class request_handler (asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, conn_sock, client_address, dict):
            self.client_address  = client_address
            self.buffer = ""
            self.dict = dict
            asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self, conn_sock)

    def readable(self):
            return True

    def writable(self):
            return False

    def handle_read(self):
            data = self.recv(SIZE)
            mtats = "msgq-stats"

            if data:
                    buffer = data
                    if buffer.lower() == mstats.lower():
                            msgout = "-- Message Queue Stats --\n"
                            for key, value in dict.items():
                                    mq = 0
                                    if dict[key].message_queue:
                                            mq = len(dict[key].message_queue)
                                    msgout += key + ":" + str(mq) + "\n"
                            self.send(msgout)
                    else:   self.send("Invalid input\n")
            else:
                    self.send("Invalid input\n")

    def handle_write(self):
            print ("--Handling read--\n")

    def handle_close(self):
            pass

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

class monitor_server (asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__ (self, ip, port, destination):
            sys.path.append('/path/')
            import dict

            self.ip = ip
            self.port = port
            self.dict = dict
            asyncore.dispatcher.__init__ (self)
            self.create_socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            self.set_reuse_addr()
            self.bind ((ip, port))
            self.listen (5)

    def writable (self):
            return 0

    def handle_read (self):
            pass

    def readable (self):
            return self.accepting

    def handle_connect (self):
            pass

    def handle_accept (self):
             (conn_sock, client_address) = self.accept()
             request_handler (conn_sock, client_address, self.destination)
```

and this is the client code:

```
class Client(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
   def __init__(self, host, port, message):
      asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
      self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      self.connect((host, port))
      print "Message being sent is "
      print message
      self.out_buffer = message

  def handle_close(self):
      self.close()

  def handle_read(self):
      print self.recv(1024)
      self.close()

 c = Client('', 6000, 'msgq-stats')
 asyncore.loop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's an error case you have to handle.  Sometimes connections will close.  It's normal for different socket errors to be encountered during development as compared to in production, since there are so many different possible errors and they almost entirely depend on the execution environment and what the program on the other side of the connection is doing and on what all the routers between the client and the server decide to do.

So, the literal answer to your question is that you need to handle this and many other socket errors in your application code.  That's part of your job when you use asyncore.  Add the necessary exception handling and mark the connection as closed when something like this happens.

A slightly better answer is that there are higher level tools that make network programming easier, and you should probably consider using those.  The big thing in this area is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).